# Running a python script within a bash file with php

Tags: php, python, bash

I am trying to run a simple python script (name.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
 name = raw_input('What is your name?\n')
 print 'Hi, %s.' % name
```

with the  following bash script(Helloworld.sh):

```
 #!/bin/bash

python name.py
```

through the following php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {

 echo shell_exec('sh /home/administrator/Desktop/Helloworld.sh');
}

  ?>
<form action="myfilename.php" method="post">
<p><Input Type = "Submit" Name ="Submit1" Value = "Save Parameters">

</form>
</p> 

</body>
</html>
```

The error in the log is:

python: can't open file 'name.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

The bash file works fine from the terminal. What should I do?

Comment: Is it in the same directory?

Comment: What value does the Bash script add?

Comment: You may want to put the full qualified path.

Comment: Why not just do: `echo shell_exec('python /home/administrator/Desktop/name.py');`?

Comment: Try giving the full path in the shell script to the directory

Comment: Could it be the PHP process is started from a different user, that does not have access over the name.py file? Maybe also check the shell script itself

Comment: Why do you mean it has started from different user? What should I do to rectify this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
BASEDIR=`dirname "${0}"`
cd "$BASEDIR"
python name.py
```

to always be run on the directory containing the script. Or if the **name.py** is in another directory, then change the `cd` command accordingly.

Comment: Both python and shell scrip are on the desktop, I have changed my shell script to:#!/bin/bash



    BASEDIR=`Desktop "${0}"`
    cd "$BASEDIR"
    python name.py................................but no luck

Comment: It's BASEDIR=`dirname "${0}"` not `BASEDIR=Desktop "${0}"`, `dirname` is a command, you don't need to modify my code, just copy and paste

Answer (score 2):

try adding the line before executing python script

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

in your bash file?

Comment: Both python and bash files are on the desktop, so I have added               cd "$(Desktop "$0")"                           This is the new error:/home/administrator/Desktop/Helloworld.sh: 3: /home/administrator/Desktop/Helloworld.sh: Desktop: not found
python: can't open file 'name.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: no, just add `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` don't change `dirname` leave it